# Handling changing of dispaly orientation android

Tags: android

I`ve locked my display orientation with

```
 this.setRequestedOrientation(
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

in my `onCreate()` method and thats, of course, works fine. Now I want to handle the changing of my display orientation. I want to rotate my ImageView the same way as it`s realized in android camera. Any ideas? 
thanks a lot

Comment: please use the search before posting duplicate questions on [SO]

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest you can add this attribute to the activity you want to check:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation"
      android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

And your activity code just override this method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

     // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

For reference:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: thanks a lot, but it shows only once "landscape" when I start my application and does not changes when I rotate it.